# encrypt with crypto, decrypt in crypto-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I am attempting to decrypt an existing encrypted payload in Postman. The encryption is happening in nodejs as shown below. I cannot modify the encryption. Note that the payload is a json object that is also base64 encoded:

```
import crypto from 'crypto'

export const encrypt = (text: any, key: string, iv: any) => {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv)
    let encrypted = cipher.update(text)
    encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()])
    return { iv: iv.toString('hex'), encryptedData: encrypted.toString('hex') }
}
```

I am attempting to decode then decrypt in Postman using crypto-js. Here is simulated code to do that:

```
var crypto = require("crypto-js");

var payload = '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'

var decodedPayload = Buffer.from(payload, 'base64').toString('utf8');
console.log('decoded: ', decodedPayload);
var parsedPayload = JSON.parse(decodedPayload);
var iv = parsedPayload.iv;
var crypttext = parsedPayload.encryptedData;
console.log('iv: ', iv);
console.log('crypttext: ', crypttext);
var key = 'fpK92jhnf914Kahqkecnml96l4apmgOf';
var plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    {
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(crypttext),
        salt: ''
    },
    Buffer.from(key),
    { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv), mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding }
)
console.log('plaintextArray: ', plaintextArray);
console.log('res: ', CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(plaintextArray));
```

I get a byte array back but not the expected values in plain text. It should be a json object. Am i missing some encoding translation somewhere? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

const payload = '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';
const key = 'fpK92jhnf914Kahqkecnml96l4apmgOf';

function decrypt(b64payload, key) {
  const decodedData = Buffer.from(b64payload, "base64").toString("utf8");
  const { iv, encryptedData } = JSON.parse(decodedData);

  return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedData, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    format: CryptoJS.format.Hex,
  }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}

console.log(decrypt(payload, key));
```

That worked for me. To be completely honest it was mostly guesswork, I suppose `decrypt` function implicitly assumes that the ciphertext is in hex and you don't have to parse it.

By the way, couldn't you just use `crypto.createDecipheriv`? I think that would be simpler, I thought you need to run it in the browser and that's why you wanted to use CryptoJS, but you used `Buffer.from` in your code. Though that can be easily replaced by `atob()` in browser environment.

Comment: Looks like I was missing the format as part of the iv. Thanks alot for the help. I am using crypto.createDecipheriv when decrypting in nodejs. My use case is having to decode in postman so my only option is using crypto-js and that library does not support createDecipheriv. I can work with your suggestion - its a big help, thank you.